# How to set Genymotion as default emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, genymotion

i cannot run my app via genymotion whenever i press run button only AVD emulator starts even genymotion is in running. it does not show in picker device.

Comment: Can you tell what is your IDE?

Comment: eclipse for mobile development